# Does magical aging have the same effect as natural aging on children?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

If an infant human was magically aged 20 years (say they encountered a ghost), would they be a fully functioning adult, or a horribly aged child?

Having an encounter with a ghost turn a nursery full of children into physically normal adults (with some 10-year-olds) seems to be what the results of the game mechanics would be.

Is that correct?

Comment: Is it possible you are confusing rules from different editions? In previous editions ghosts could cause unnatural aging but they do not have any such power in 5th edition.

Comment: @AllanMills No? I see Horrifying Visage Action: "If the save fails by 5 or more, the target also ages 1d4 x 10 years".

Comment: @aschepler Sorry. Missed that bit. I think in previous editions you just had to see the ghost.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym That's fine as an answer, see [Does "Ask the DM / GM" equate to "Primarily opinion based?"](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7353/52137) from the FAQ for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### “Ages” means what the DM decides it means

It’s not a term that is defined in the rules and the age of a creature (except dragons) has no mechanical effect in the rules.

Whether the aged creature is “normal” for its age or whether you have a Tom Hanks [Big](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094737/) situation is up to the DM.